# PHP date is wrong for early 2021 dates

Tags: php, date

When I print a date from a timestamp, I'm getting the following results:

```
$date = "2021-01-03 10:45:06";
echo date('M j, o', strtotime($date)); // prints Jan 3, 2020, when it should say Jan 3, 2021

$date = "2021-01-04 10:45:06";
echo date('M j, o', strtotime($date)); // prints Jan 4, 2021, which is expected
```

For some reason, the year in the first date is showing up as 2020 instead of 2021. I'm using PHP version 7.1.33

Comment: Then why use `o` instead of `Y`?

Comment: I didn't know the difference. The examples on php.net give the same results for each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), the `o` formatting option:

> ISO-8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead.

The ISO week that January 3, 2021 falls into is in the 2020 ISO year.

To avoid this issue, (unless you are working specifically with ISO dates) use the `Y` format option.